# iOS App Crashing Upon Relaunching App

Tags: ios, objective-c, autologin

We are working with a developer that is having a hard time debugging an issue so I thought I would post here.

When we receive the build and install the app it will work fine, but after the app being in the background for a few days when we tap on the icon it will show the  loading screen and then crash.

When tapping the button twice we will see the app in the background and when we bring it to the foreground it is frozen.

The same similar issue happens if we install over a previous build it crashes upon initial launch.

One of my developer friends said it might have to do with the auto login. We have Crashlytics setup but it's not catching these crashes. Does anyone have any ideas of what this could be?

Comment: It would be impossible to help you without code. Maybe the developer can check this scenario by first running the app on simulator with old codebase and then re-running the app with the same identifier with the new code base

Comment: I have access to the code.

Comment: if you are willing to share it.. I can look at it

Comment: Ankit - I would be more than happy to. What is your Github username?

Comment: username : Ankit8946

Comment: Ankit. What is your skype I'll message you on there. Mine is ngaymerjones - we are willing to pay you if you can help us resolve this. Thank you.